# How to invoke with reflection a Java function which has method reference as parameters

Tags: java, elasticsearch, methods, reflection, reference

A class (from Elasticsearch Rest API) has a **protected method** that I want to invoke. The problem is that this method has **method reference parameters** :

```
protected <Req extends ActionRequest, Resp> Resp performRequestAndParseEntity(
            Req request,
            CheckedFunction<Req, Request, IOException> requestConverter,
            CheckedFunction<XContentParser, Resp, IOException> entityParser,
            Set<Integer> ignores, Header... headers) throws IOException {
    return performRequest(request, requestConverter, (response) ->
        parseEntity(response.getEntity(), entityParser), ignores, headers);
}
```

In the API, this method is called that way:

```
DeleteIndexResponse deleteIndexResponse = restHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(
    deleteIndexRequest,
    Request::deleteIndex,
    DeleteIndexResponse::fromXContent,
    Collections.emptySet(),
    headers
);
```

Java tells me that "**The target type of this expression must be a functional interface**" for `DeleteIndexRequest::deleteIndex` and `DeleteIndexResponse::fromXContent`.

My (not working) solution:

```
java.lang.Class clazz = restHighLevelClient.getClass();
java.lang.reflect.Method performRequestAndParseEntity = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(
    "performRequestAndParseEntity",
    Object.class,
    org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction.class,
    org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction.class,
    java.util.Set.class,
    org.apache.http.Header.class
);
performRequestAndParseEntity.setAccessible(true);

org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexResponse 
deleteIndexResponse = (org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexResponse)
    performRequestAndParseEntity.invoke(
        restHighLevelClient,
        deleteByIndexRequest,
        org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexRequest::deleteIndex,
        org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexResponse::fromXContent,
        java.util.Collections.emptySet(),
        null
    )
;
```

**EDIT**

I also tried to cast `deleteIndex` (and `fromXContent`) to `CheckedFunction`, i.e. calling in `invoke`:

```
performRequestAndParseEntity.invoke(
    ...,
   ((org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction) org.elasticsearch.client.Request::deleteIndex),
    ...
);
```

I also tried to define a variable outside the `invoke` call:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction deleteIndexFunction =
    org.elasticsearch.client.Request::deleteIndex;
```

And:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction deleteIndexFunction =
    (org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction) org.elasticsearch.client.Request::deleteIndex;
```

For all, Java is telling that: "**The type Request does not define deleteIndex(Object) that is applicable here**", and the same for `fromXContent`

For information, `deleteIndex` is defined that way:

```
static Request deleteIndex(DeleteIndexRequest deleteIndexRequest) {
    ...
}
```

And `CheckedFunction` is:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedFunction<T, R, E extends Exception> {
    R apply(T t) throws E;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
I also tried to parametrize the `CheckedFunction` Object with similar same result (**"The type Request does not define deleteIndex(DeleteIndexRequest) that is applicable here"**):

```
org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction<org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexRequest, org.elasticsearch.client.Request, Exception> deleteIndexFunction =
        (org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction<org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexRequest, org.elasticsearch.client.Request, Exception>) org.elasticsearch.client.Request::deleteIndex;
```

I think that the problem is the `deleteIndex` function is not public.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `Method.invoke` declares all arguments as `Object` regardless of what the actual argument types are. This means that `Object` is the type that the compiler is trying to turn your method reference into an implementation of, which can't work because `Object` is not a functional interface.

To fix this, cast each method reference to the type it's actually supposed to be - `org.elasticsearch.common.CheckedFunction`. The compiler will pick this up as the intended type of the method reference, allowing it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question with those tests.
With my last try (defining outside variables), `invoke` seems OK but the variable definition fails with "The type Request does not define deleteIndex(Object) that is applicable here"